# What is the tutte polynomial

Tags: graph-theory, geometry

I am really stuck on how to work out the tutte polynomial so any help would be great thanks.

G is a graph with 2 vertices, joined by n edges. 
How to you show what the tutte polynomial is? 
And what is the relationship between this graph and the graph of Cn? I do understand that they are isomorphic of one another.

Comment: Why not have a look at the Wikipedia article?  There's a worked example there.  If you've understood that, you should be able to work out the Tutte polynomial of your graph.

Comment: Yes, I have read that and it helped a bit however I don't really see the relationship between this graph and Cn.